# Generic information about interface implemented by field type in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections

Let's suppose we have a type `CustomMap<A, B>` which extends `CommonMap<C, D>` which in turn implements `Map<E, F>`.

Naturally one would expect that `A == C == E`, but it's not always so - you can have a `CustomMap<V>` implementing `Map<String, V>` for example.

The question is, let's suppose I have a `Field`, and `field.getType()` is some interface or class implementing `Map<K, V>`. The type itself may be non generic, may be generic but with generic signature differing from `<K, V>`, etc. How go I get `K` and `V` type parameters of `Map` using reflection?

Comment: You can't. Java has [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) which means that the type parameters are erased upon compiling the code. The resulting type is the most concrete bound type, which might be `Object`.

Comment: This is not correct, type information is retained on fields and you can get it via `field.getGenericType()`.

Comment: It’s possible, but the code handling all corner cases correctly, would be horrible. E.g., the field’s type may refer to type variables of the declaring class, whose bounds refer to type variable of the outer class of the declaring class. Similar corner cases may exist when traversing the super type hierarchy of the field type, to substitute the type variables with their actual arguments. Plus, there are no public implementation types or factory methods to produce an object to express the result (i.e. to construct a `ParameterizedType` for `Map<X,Y>` after you found the actual `X` and `Y`).

Comment: It's somewhat cumbersome but totally doable in practice. I will post a gist of what I have learned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that one will have to write code which crawls type information, remembers which type corresponds to type parameter names, and then do the substitution. The code may vary depending on the specifics, such as class/interface, etc, but the core of it is:

```
    // Contains mappings such as K -> Integer, V -> String
    Map<String, Type> typeParameters = new HashMap<>();
    ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    // Actual type arguments of a specific parametrized type, e.g. <Integer, PARAM> - 
    // the latter is resolved against typeParameters map
    Type[] typeArguments = pType.getActualTypeArguments();

    cls = ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType());

    // Named arguments of type as declared, e.g. <K, V>
    TypeVariable<?>[] typeParamDecls = cls.getTypeParameters();

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(typeParamDecls.length, typeArguments.length); i++) {
        Type value;
        if (typeArguments[i] instanceof TypeVariable) {
            value = typeParameters.get(((TypeVariable<?>) typeArguments[i]).getName());
        } else {
            value = typeArguments[i];
        }

        typeParameters.put(typeParamDecls[i].getName(), value);
    }
```

This needs to be applied recursively to `cls.getGenericSuperclass()` / `cls.getGenericInterfaces()` until you find the type that you wanted in the first place. There may be edge cases if raw types are used anywhere.

Comment: The type is not always a `ParameterizedType`. Think of `class StringMap implements Map<String,String>` or, real life example `class Properties implements Map<Object,Object>`. In these cases, the type is just a `Class` but `getGenericSuperclass()`/ `getGenericInterfaces()` still does it’s job (in other words, it’s not about raw types). Further, substitution may also be applied recursively to the type arguments, think of `class StringMap extends MultiMap<String,String> {} class MultiMap<K,V> implements Map<K,List<V>> {}` (but there’s no API to create a `Type` object representing `List<String>`)…

Comment: Yes, you just go to superclass if it's not `ParametrizedType`. If you see how `typeParameters` are handled, they are applied recursively.

Comment: There is no recursion in your code. There is just an `instanceof TypeVariable` which evaluates to `false` in my `implements Map<K,List<V>>` example, as `List<V>` is not a type variable but a parameterized type (referring to a type variable which your code does not substitute with its actual argument).

Comment: This is because the code is not supposed to be mindlessly copy-pasted, rather provide guidance.

Comment: It doesn’t handle my example. Point.

Comment: Maybe it's because we're not on Odesk?

Comment: I have no idea what this comment is supposed to mean. You have asked a question here and I told you in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895908/69905788?noredirect=1#comment123566332_69895908) that a correct solution handling all cases is horribly complicated. Now, you’ve posted an incomplete solution that is failing on even simpler cases, not even coming close to the corner cases mentioned in that comment and are refusing to admit that it is incomplete. How is that helpful to anyone?

Comment: Please avoid asking question in comments; this should be done using "Ask Question" button.

Comment: I didn’t ask a question. I told you that *your question* has not been answered by this “answer”.